# Finding Resources for Real Anlalysis

Tags: real-analysis

I'm searching for resources and worksheets to the concepts of real analysis. Convergence of series, proving via contradiction and Induction and recursive series.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a library of real analysis sources for free.  There are many older textbooks that you can find on the internet.  Don't neglect these.  Mathematics is not like biology, changing radically every decade.  Analysis texts from half a century ago are still worth studying.

Don't miss the **American Institute of Mathematics** with their approved textbook list:

https://aimath.org/textbooks/

[American Institute of Mathematics](https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/)

The current listing for real analysis includes these:

1. Basic Analysis: Introduction to Real Analysis.
   Jiří Lebl  https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/lebl-ra/
2. Introduction to Real Analysis.
   William F. Trench  https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/trench/
3. Elementary Real Analysis.
   Brian S. Thomson, Judith B. Bruckner, Andrew M. Bruckner  https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/thomson-bruckner-bruckner/
4. Mathematical Analysis I.
   Elias Zakon https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/zakon/
5. How We Got from There to Here: A Story of Real Analysis.
   Robert Rogers and Eugene Boman https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/rogers-boman/

Comment: At first thanks for the great recommendations, but the problem with most of these books is that the problems aren't often answered. which is hard to me , as I have understood the lessons but want to practice intensively, because there aren't many exercises in my course

Comment: Real analysis textbooks do not answer all of the problems.  This isn't calculus or high school.  You will have to work.  Fortunately you have StackExchange if you know how to use it.  There is always help available here if you ask correctly.